# Can't rsync locally on synology NAS

Tags: rsync

I'm logged in to my Synology NAS and although I can rsync from my servers to the NAS and vice versa, I can't use rsync where the source and destination are both on the DiskStation.

```
midnight my_user /tmp> rsync -Pauvvv synoproxy.conf del.del
sending incremental file list
[sender] make_file(synoproxy.conf,*,0)
send_file_list done
send_files starting
server_recv(2) starting pid=15513
ERROR: module is read only
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1034) [Receiver=3.0.8]
[Receiver] _exit_cleanup(code=1, file=main.c, line=1034): about to call exit(1)
rsync error: rsync service is no running (code 43) at io.c(653) [sender=3.0.8]
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=43, file=io.c, line=653): about to call exit(43)
midnight my_user /tmp>
```

I don't know why I'm having module issues with the syntax I've provided. Why is this producing an error?

Comment: How do you logon to your NAS for this, via SSH or is there a way to open a terminal from the web interface pls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears one has to use absolute directory like /volume1/homes/username/...

Comment: Oh my lord thank you SOO much! This is the only thing that worked for me. Also note that

Comment: 7 years later this is still valid and correct advice.

Answer (score 5):

Reviving this thread, I stumbled upon the same issue with a more recent version of a synology NAS. It appears synology runs an rsync daemon, so the syntax isn't the same as for regular paths.

First you can

```
nmap -p 873 --script rsync-list-modules <NAS_IP>
```

to get a list of your rsync modules that the rsync daemon knows about. As far as I understood, the names are those of the root folders in your NAS.

Then instead of

```
rsync /path/to/src user@IP:/path/to/dst
```

Use

```
rsync /path/to/src user@IP::modulename/path/in/module
```

There can also be permission issues, but I think that's at least one part of the issue.

Comment: This resolved my issue on a new Synology NAS where rsync seemed not to work out of the box.  It must be the new daemon, as noted...

Answer (score 1):

Following https://serverfault.com/a/454876/589058, what I did to solve this on Synology server is:

```
1) download rsync-x86 from https://github.com/JBBgameich/rsync-static/releases;
2) scp /path/to/local/rsync-x86 my_server:/tmp/;
3) ssh my_server;
4) chmod +x /tmp/rsync-x86;
5) exit;
6) rsync -avzPh --rsync-path=/tmp/rsync-x86 source dest;
```

Comment: Best answer at bottom of page as usual .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read on [a Synology forum thread](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=23595), I'd try to update the firmware and your NAS device and see if that resolves the problem. Perhaps also [this post](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=225&t=62407&p=246003&hilit=rsync#p246003) is interesting.

Comment: Unfortunately, no dice. I'm at the most up to date firmware already (new unit).